# cp says "same file" for two different directories

Tags: directory, cp

I have directory A with subdirectory B and am trying to copy everything from B to A. Within A, I run

```
cp -ar B/ ~/A,
```

and get the message that

```
"cp: 'B/' and '/u/username/A/B' are the same file"
```

However, I'm not sure why it thinks the destination would involve B.

Comment: Where are these `â` coming from?

Answer (score 4):

In general, this attempts to copy B, not its contents, into A.  Since B is already a subdirectory of A, `cp` is rightly saying that the source and destination are the same file.

If you instead want to copy the contents of B into A, you want:

```
cp -ar /path/to/A/B/* /path/to/A/
```

If A is your current working directory, then this works instead:

```
cp -ar B/* .
```

Comment: His current directory is already `A`. So, `cp -ar B/* .` will do.

Answer (score 1):

The command `cp -ar B/ ~/A` won't only copy the contents of `B` but the whole `B` itself which is already present in `A`. So, try running `cp -ar B/* .` within the directory `A`.